# How to mock authentication user on unit tests with Codeception in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, codeception, laravel-authentication

I have to convert my unit tests to codeception. I need to use loginWithFakeUser() function from this article - [How to mock authentication user on unit test in Laravel?](https://medium.com/laravel-tips/how-to-mock-authentication-user-on-unit-test-in-laravel-1441d491d82c)

```
public function loginWithFakeUser() {
    $user = new User([
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'yish'
    ]);
    $this->be($user);
}
```

How can I use the `$this->be()` when my class is already extending `\Codeception\Test\Unit`? I don't know what should I `use ..` or how to use properly. Putting the function loginWithFakeUser() inside this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithAuthentication;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithSession;

class AdminTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit {
    use InteractsWithAuthentication;
    use InteractsWithSession;
}
```

Gives me an error:

> [ErrorException] Undefined property: AdminTest::$app

I'm not sure how can I set the $app variable. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this by mocking the `Auth` class.

```
$oUser = new User([
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'yish'
]);

Auth::shouldReceive('check')->once()->andReturn(true);
Auth::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn($oUser);
```

Where in my actual code it uses it as:

```
if(Auth::check() === true) {
    $sName = Auth::user()->name;
}
```